# ASP.NET MVC Template problem

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, templates

I try to create template and this template should be from 1 element - textarea, but this textarea should be extended to TinyMCE control.
I try to do it via following ascx control:

```
<textarea id="SubComment" name="SubComment" style="width: 80%">
<% = Html.Encode(ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue) %></textarea>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        tinyMCE.init({
            // General options
            mode: "textareas",
            theme: "advanced",
            plugins: "spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,imagemanager,videoupload",

            // Theme options
            theme_advanced_buttons1: <% = txtAdvButtons %>,
            theme_advanced_buttons2: "tablecontrols",
            theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "",
            theme_advanced_resizing: true,
            onchange_callback: "changed",

            // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
            content_css: "css/example.css",

            // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
            template_external_list_url: "js/template_list.js",
            external_link_list_url: "js/link_list.js",
            external_image_list_url: "js/image_list.js",
            media_external_list_url: "js/media_list.js",

            // Replace values for the template plugin
            template_replace_values: {
                username: "Some User",
                staffid: "991234"
            },

            setup: function(editor) {
                editor.addButton('myupload', {
                    title: 'Insert image',
                    image: '/tiny_mce/plugins/imagemanager/pages/im/img/insertimage.gif',
                    onclick: function() {
                        mcImageManager.upload({
                            path: '{0}',
                            onupload: function(info) {
                                var i, html = '';

                                for (i = 0; i < info.files.length; i++)
                                    html += '<img src="' + info.files[i].url + '" />';

                                editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, html);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }

        });
</script>
```

but when I try to use this template I see simple textarea. How to apply this javascript extention (it works correctly out of ascx control)? 
Thanks

Comment: Are you including the jquery script with each template?  You should put that script tag in the Head.

Comment: when it put in the Head of view - it does not work via template and I try to find other ways

Answer (score 1):

So I read up on the documentation for tinyMCE and it turns out that the code you posted there should be placed in the Head tag or another script file.

Change your textarea to this:

```
<textarea name="SubComment" class="tinyMCETextArea" style="width: 80%">
```

And in your tinyMCE initialization code:

```
$(function(){
    tinyMCE.init({
        /// all your options
        editor_selector: "tinyMCETextArea",
        /// More stuff
    });
});
```

Comment: how it can help me? This editor shows correctly if textarea it put to view directly, without template. If via template - then it is shown as simple textarea

Comment: Try wrapping the tinyMCE in the document ready. I have updated my example.

Comment: It sounds like your template is not being rendered.  Are you sure you correctly mapped the type you want to the template?

Comment: template is rendering as simple textbox (I use Object.ascx as template, is it correct?)

Comment: No, the template should be named the same thing as the model you want to use in the rendering.  If you have a model called MCETextAreaModel, you would have a partial view called MCETextAreaModel.aspx.  If you are simply passing a string to use as the field (not a model), you may want to just use a partial view and call Html.RenderPartial("MCETextAreaModel", Model.MCETextAreaModel)

Comment: thanks, I solved this problem, not necessary "id" attribute to textarea element.

Comment: your edited answer is correct (without "id" attribute). I did many things via templates, in really only 1 the simplest action was necessary...